# How to rectify this errors..?

Tags: asp.net

> The type 'Sdi.Pss.Site1' already contains the definition for 'logout'
>
> The type 'Sdi.Pss.Site1' already contains the definition for 'btnfresh'
>
> The type 'Sdi.Pss.Site1' already contains the definition for 'lblshow value'

Comment: I'd have thought it self evident, these aren't esoteric error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by changing the ids of the controls. It sounds like you copy/pasted some controls and thus have two with id `logout` etc. Just do a quick search and rename the duplicates.